# Strange output when using system("clear") command in C program

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I have the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define dimensions 5

int RandomNumInRange(int M, int N)
{
    return M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1);
}

char ** CreateWorld(int dim)
{
    int i,j;
    char **world = malloc(dim *sizeof(char*));

    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    world[i]=malloc(dim*sizeof(char));

for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
        world[i][j]=42;

return world;
}


void CreateCastle(char **world)
{

//assuming world is big enough
//to hold a match of 2
int randRow,randCol;

//1 to dimension -2 so we can spawn a 3x3 castle
    randRow = RandomNumInRange(1,dimensions-2);
    randCol = RandomNumInRange(1,dimensions-2);

printf("position: %d %d\n", randRow, randCol);
world[randRow][randCol]='c';
//fill the rest so castle is 3x3
//assuming there is enough space for that
world[randRow-1][randCol-1]=35;
world[randRow-1][randCol]=35;
world[randRow-1][randCol+1]=35;
world[randRow][randCol-1]=35;
world[randRow][randCol+1]=35;
world[randRow+1][randCol-1]=35;
world[randRow+1][randCol]=35;
world[randRow+1][randCol+1]=35;

}


void DisplayWorld(char** world)
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<dimensions;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<dimensions;j++)
    {
        printf("%c",world[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main(void){

system("clear");


int i,j;
srand (time(NULL));


char **world = CreateWorld(dimensions);
DisplayWorld(world);
CreateCastle(world);

printf("Castle Positions:\n");
DisplayWorld(world);

//free allocated memory
free(world);

//3 star strats

char ***world1 = malloc(3 *sizeof(char**));

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    world1[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(char*));

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        world1[i][j]="\u254B";

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("%s",world1[i][j]);
puts("");
}
free(world1);
//end
return 0 ;
}
```

If I use the `system("clear")` command, I get a line consisting of "[3;J" 
followed by an expected output. If I run the program again, I get the same gibberish, then many blank newlines, then the expected output. If I put the `system("clear")` command in comments then both the "[3;J" and the blank newlines don't show and the output is expected.

**Edit:** it seems the error is not in the code, but rather in the way the terminal on my system is (not) set. Thank you all for your input, I definitely have a lot of interesting stuff to read and learn now.

Comment: DO NOT USE `system("clear");` it's not standard c, it has nothing to do with c in fact, the only relation of it to c is the `system()` function which executes an external command. You don't ever need `system("clear")` and it only works on very specific systems.

Comment: Also, you `free()` `world` but there's a memory leak because you don't `free()` the pointers allocated and stored in `world`, you need to iterate through them just like you did to allocate them, and use `free()` you need many `free()` calls as many `malloc()`'s you have. Finally, always check the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, I agree that `system("clear")` is probably inappropriate, and that the `"clear"` part has nothing to do with C.  Nevertheless, it works perfectly fine for me on CentOS 7, and I'd expect it to work in many other places, too.

Comment: In fact, IIRC, the DOS command was `cls`, not `clear`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I noticed that when I was reading your comment! It's very common to see `system("cls")` and I didn't pay attention to that in fact. Sorry.

Comment: @Σπύρος Γούλας, if you're trying to draw on the screen in text mode, instead of just outputting a stream of text, then I strongly recommend that you select and use a library appropriate for that purpose.  The longstime standby for this kind of thing is one version or another of [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29), but there are other alternatives.

Comment: What kind of terminal window are you using? Is it gnome-terminal, Mac Terminal, a cmd window on Windows?

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for your advice, will be sure to check it out.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I use the default terminal in a linux mint os.

Comment: What happens when you run the `clear` command by typing it in your terminal?

Comment: @n.m. Exactly the same unexpected behaviour! Gibberish then blank lines. Woa, did not try that before you mentioned it.

Comment: So it is clear that your problem has absolutely nothing to do with C or system or even programming. You simply have your terminal set up incorrectly. Ask Mint Linux people what you have done wrong. You could (or rather should) have done this check yourself before posting here.

Comment: In the Mint terminal window, what is the output of `echo $TERM` ?

Comment: @n.m. I did not know the problem had nothing to do with C . Even then, i did use the (rather broad) unix tag for my question. Don't be mean..

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The program 'xterm' is currently not installed.

Comment: `clear`, `tput` and `ncurses` all rely on terminal capabilities (TERMCAP). Your system might not even have termcap installed to properly generate escape sequences for your terminal or `TERM` is set to wrong type.

Answer (score 2):

The codes being sent by your `clear` command from don't seem to be compatible with the Gnome terminal emulator, which I believe is what you would be using.

The normal control codes to clear a console are `CSI H CSI J`. (`CSI` is the Control Sequence Initializer: an escape character `\033` followed by a <kbd>[</kbd>). `CSI H` sends the cursor to the home position, and `CSI J` clears from the cursor position to the end of the screen. You could also use `CSI 2 J` which clears the entire screen.

On Linux consoles and some terminal emulators, you can use `CSI 3 J` to clear both the entire screen *and* the scrollback. I would consider it unfriendly to do this (and the clear command installed on my system doesn't.)

CSI sequences can typically contain semicolons to separate numeric arguments. However, the `J` command doesn't accept more than one numeric argument and the semicolon seems to cause Gnome terminal to fail to recognize the control sequence. In any event, I don't believe Gnome terminal supports `CSI 3 J`.

The `clear` command normally uses the terminfo database to find the correct control sequences for the terminal. It identifies the terminal by using the value of the `TERM` environment variable, which suggests that you have to wrong value for that variable. Try setting `export TERM=xterm` and see if you get different results. If that works, you'll have to figure out where Linux Mint configures environment variables and fix it.

On the whole, you shouldn't need to use `system("clear")` to clear your screen; it's entirely too much overhead for such a simple task. You would be better off using `tputs` from the `ncurses` package. However, that also uses the terminfo database, so you will have to fix your `TERM` setting in any case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. Lots of things i did not know there. export TERM=xterm does not change the aforementioned behaviour.

Comment: @ΣπύροςΓούλας That's interesting. What do you see if you type `tput clear|hd`? I would expect the output to be `1b 5b 48 1b 5b 32 4a`

Comment: it is 00000000  1b 5b 33 3b 4a 1b 5b 48  1b 5b 32 4a              |.[3;J.[H.[2J|
0000000c

Comment: Does that change if you run `TERM=xterm tput clear|hd` ?

Comment: it displays 00000000  1b 5b 48 1b 5b 32 4a                              |.[H.[2J|
00000007

Comment: i checked the link you provided. Now clear does not display the strange output, but it still adds empty new lines.

Comment: @ΣπύροςΓούλας: The interesting thing is that `TERM=xterm tput clear` produces the correct codes for your terminal, but you said that `TERM=xterm clear` didn't work. I would expect them to produce the same codes. Anyway, you could just the `TERM=xterm tput clear` command instead of `clear`, but really I think you would be better off using the `tputs` function as I suggested in the last paragraph of my answer. There is really no point firing up a new shell to execute an external program to clear the screen when you could do that by writing seven bytes to `stdout` :)

Answer (score -1):

You can sent the output of `clear` to `/dev/null`
Just use: `clear>/dev/null`

Comment: You understand that the entire purpose of `clear` is to send some output to the terminal, right? `clear > /dev/null` would have no purpose whatsoever.